# problems with the position of a Row

Tags: flutter, dart, widget

I'm building a widget for an application. I have a problem to set a position of a row.

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2Yzp.jpg)

I don't how to set the position of the two icon button where is the black rectangle.
I tried to use main/crossAxisAlignment but I have only obtain that the row move from center to right.
Here is my code:

```
class CustomCardDetail extends StatelessWidget {
  CustomCardDetail({
    this.containerHeight,
    this.containerWidth,
    @required this.image,
    this.backgroundColor,
    this.colorTitle,
    @required this.title,
    this.titleFontSize,
    this.titleFontFamily,
    this.titleFontWeight,
    @required this.content,
    this.contentColor,
    this.contentFontSize,
    this.contentFontFamily,
    this.contentFontWeight,
    @required this.onPressedFavoriteButton,
    @required this.onPressedShareButton,
  });

  final double containerHeight, containerWidth, titleFontSize, contentFontSize;
  final String image, title, titleFontFamily, content, contentFontFamily;
  final Color backgroundColor, colorTitle, contentColor;
  final FontWeight titleFontWeight, contentFontWeight;
  final Function onPressedFavoriteButton, onPressedShareButton;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      height: containerHeight,
      width: containerWidth,
      color: backgroundColor,
      child: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            child: Image(
              image: AssetImage(image),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.red,
              height: 170,
              child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                children: [
                  Text(
                    title == null ? 'TITLE' : title,
                    style: TextStyle(
                      color: colorTitle,
                      fontSize: titleFontSize,
                      fontFamily: titleFontFamily,
                      fontWeight: titleFontWeight,
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                    child: Text(
                      content == null ? 'CONTENT' : content,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: contentColor,
                        fontSize: contentFontSize,
                        fontFamily: contentFontFamily,
                        fontWeight: contentFontWeight,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Row(
                    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                    children: [
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.favorite_border,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onPressed: onPressedFavoriteButton,
                      ),
                      IconButton(
                        icon: Icon(
                          Icons.share_rounded,
                          color: Colors.white,
                        ),
                        onPressed: onPressedShareButton,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add spacer between  padding and row

```
Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
                children: [
                  Container(
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage(image),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
                    child: Container(
                      color: Colors.red,
                      height: 170,
                      child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                        children: [
                          Text(
                            title == null ? 'TITLE' : title,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              color: colorTitle,
                              fontSize: titleFontSize,
                              fontFamily: titleFontFamily,
                              fontWeight: titleFontWeight,
                            ),
                          ),
                          Padding(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 15.0),
                            child: Text(
                              content == null ? 'CONTENT' : content,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                color: contentColor,
                                fontSize: contentFontSize,
                                fontFamily: contentFontFamily,
                                fontWeight: contentFontWeight,
                              ),
                            ),
                          ),
                Spacer(), ////////// add spacer
                          Row(
                            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.end,
                            children: [
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.favorite_border,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                onPressed: onPressedFavoriteButton,
                              ),
                              IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.share_rounded,
                                  color: Colors.white,
                                ),
                                onPressed: onPressedShareButton,
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                        ],
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
```